# Browser without video playback

Tags: browser, video, video-streaming, adobe-flash, browser-add-ons

I am trying to avoid any kind of sexual stimulation and want to block video content on any browser. I was looking for browsers which provide this functionality but could not find one. These are the browsers which I found

1. Atlas Browser
2. Lightning Browser
3. No image Browser
4. Habit Browser

All these browsers block only images in the browser. But I need a specific one which can block videos only. Finally, I found one such that blocks both images and videos but this functionality cannot be separated. The browser is Purity - Safe Porn less Browser.

I want to know if this functionality is separatable? Can we block images and videos separately? This browser needs subscription ; so does anyone know about any such browser that does not support flash or video files.

Important question : Can we practically block images and videos separately or are they correlated?

Comment: You could use Firefox and go into the about:config and disable all the video codecs so that videos will not play.  As for images, just use an extension/add-on like "Image Block X" for example.

Comment: @Archerbob...Thanks. Indeed a great solution. Do you know any way to make these changes permanent. Like deleting that codec settings or some sort of other way.

Comment: @Archerbob ...what needs to be disabled to block downloads also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with help of Archerbob's comment. We can disable all video codecs and permanently lock this setting using various blockers available on Playstore such as BlockerX and Blockerhero. I added *about:config* to the blocked keywords and now I am totally blocked out of this setting.

This blocking codec thing did not work well with youtube but somehow solved my problem. Anybody looking for a solution can give it a try.

Comment: I assume your a parent, trying to prevent a child from accessing certain content on the web.  Unfortunately, there's no way to really achieve that but with supervision, because anyone with a modicum of computing knowledge, even a child, can get around and circumvent any measures taken to block or block access to such content... this was the way it was even when I was going to school.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know any browsers, but if your phone is rooted and have magisk installed you could install energized protection a magisk module to completely block sexual contents on your device, so even if you search for it on any browser in your phone no results will showing up..

P.s i have tested this method with chrome browser and it works, and should work with any other major browser too.

Comment: @YomaAroriode....No such filter can block porn completely. I have rich experience dealing with such apps and modules. So my question stays the same.

Comment: Energized module uses hosts based blocking. This cannot provide the granular filtering OP is seeking. Consider telegraph.co.uk or timesofindia.com. Even though they operate as "media/news" website, the unsolicited and erotically charged suggestions post, images and videos they display makes these websites as "Adult only / 18+ only"! Imagine OP being following up a tech/political news article link and being exposed to sexually stimulating media (as a suggestion between the article or at the end of it) they want to avoid.

Comment: oh okay, thanks for the info it is noted...

Comment: I sort of wonder if what the OP really needs is a Firewall

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the "Text Mode" extension from the Google Play store for Chrome, blocks images, videos and flash content.